# ASP.NET MVC5: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use asp.net mvc5 with EF, in this few string i received "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection". What's wrong?

```
public JsonResult GetResponibleParty()
{
    List<CI_ResponsibleParty> resParty;
    using (MetabaseDbContext context = new MetabaseDbContext())
    {
        resParty = context.SetOfResponsibleParty.ToList();
        return Json(resParty, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }       
}
```

Comment: can you show what `CI_ResponsibleParty` contains? Could be that it has some refferences, that doesn't load with `ToList()`, but they need after. So it's really better to create `ResponsiblePartyViewModel` that has only properties that you need this will definatly solve your problem.

Comment: Where this error is shown? Could you show whole class?

Comment: teo van kot: yes, you are right. Trouble was in LazyLoading process.

Comment: Turn lazy loading off, add/or `.AsNoTracking()` just before you do `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
In this case me helped 2 methods:

```
1) context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
2) or using .Include()
```

Comment: The solution to this problem is to return view models instead of Entity Framework models.

Comment: But in this controller's method me need return Json

Comment: What you ultimately need to do is return a simple object that you can map your EF model to and return that instead of your EF model. This object is often called the View Model or a DTO (Data Transfer Object). You never want to either accept or return database model objects in your controller actions.

Comment: The DTO / ViewModel has fixed my problem, I can't believe I missed this!

Answer (score 1):

Move your return statement after the using block. You have already created a list and held it in a variable.

```
public JsonResult GetResponibleParty()
{
    List<CI_ResponsibleParty> resParty;
    using (MetabaseDbContext context = new MetabaseDbContext())
    {
        resParty = context.SetOfResponsibleParty.ToList();
    }       
    return Json(resParty, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue here.

Comment: Thx, but this dont work =)